# Chaining Functional Interfaces - IntUnaryOperator vs UnaryOperator

Tags: java, lambda, unary-operator

I'm still learning functional interfaces. I'd like to know why I'm able to chain a `UnaryOperator` to the end of a `Function`, but not an `IntUnaryOperator` to the end of the same Function.

```
UnaryOperator <String> twoOfMe = s -> s + s;
Function <String, Integer> convertMe = s -> Integer.parseInt (s);

UnaryOperator <Integer> twiceMe = n -> 2*n;

IntUnaryOperator doubleMe = n -> 2*n;

int a = twoOfMe.andThen(convertMe).andThen(twiceMe).apply ("2");

int b = twoOfMe.andThen(convertMe).andThen(doubleMe).apply ("2");
```

---

`int a` works with `twiceMe` but `int b` doesn't work with the `doubleMe`.

Thanks

Edit:
It says incompatible types. Required int. Found java.lang.Object

Comment: what do you mean by "doesnt work" ? Exception ? warning ? not the expected result ?

Comment: Simply because andThen() takes a Function as argument, and UnaryOperator extends Function, but IntUnaryOperator does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after)` expects a `Function` argument. `UnaryOperator<Integer>` is a sub-interface of `Function<Integer,Integer>`, which matches. `IntUnaryOperator` has no relation to the `Function` interface, so `doubleMe` cannot be passed to `andThen`.

Comment: So simple. Very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `IntUnaryOperator` maps an `int` to an `int`, and Function `<String, Integer> convertMe` is returning an `Integer`, not an `int`. You cannot chain them.

You can declare `ToIntFunction<String> convertMe = Integer::parseInt;`, then you could chain them.

```
UnaryOperator<String> twoOfMe = s -> s + s;
ToIntFunction<String> convertMe = Integer::parseInt;
IntUnaryOperator doubleMe = n -> 2*n;
int b = twoOfMe.andThen(convertMe).andThen(doubleMe).apply ("2");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into `IntUnaryOperator` class you will see that it doesn't extend any interfaces and on the other hand `UnaryOperator` does extend `Function` interface.

The code you provided doesn't work with `IntUnaryOperator` because it expects `Function` which is not what the `IntUnaryOperator` really is.